# How do I remove overflow characters or append characters in a given string in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, resize

I basically want to have an arbitrary length string but a fixed size output string. So if I assign `x` a string of 10 characters, I want to end up with a string of 5 characters at the second `printf`. And if `x` is 3 characters, I wanna add on blanks to make the string 5 characters.
Here is my code so far, but its not working because I can't even access an index, it segfaults;

```
int main()
{
    char x[] = "d dddddddd";
    printf(x);
    printf("");
    // separate
    printf(x[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks, I wonder whether this is possible in C, but you could also attempt it in C++

EDIT:
My 2 codes are here, they both overflow;

```
char first[40];
char g[] = "     Level %d      %d Fruit    %d:%d      ";
char d[41] = {0};   
strncpy(d, g, 40);
if(strlen(d) < 40) {
    for(i = strlen(d); i < 40; i++) {
        d[i] = ' ';
    }
}
n = sprintf(first, d, gol, gift, minutes, secs );
```

2nd strategy;

```
char first[40];
char b[40];
strncpy(b, g, sizeof(b));
fgets(b, 40, stdin);                          
n = sprintf(first, b, gol, gift, minutes, secs );
```

Print my n onto the game's screen, I get my text and some unknown characters following. Sorry that I can't post the whole game code because its 4000 lines long split in 10 files. I wold appreciate a completely different way of getting a string of only 40 characters from a string of more characters.

Comment: 1. Pay attention to your compiler errors and warnings. 2. Get a book, this is really basic stuff. 3. Read the printf documentation.  4. Pick a language, C and C++ are different.  5. Arrays are not resizable in C

Comment: Maybe something like `for (i=0; i<5 && x[i]; i++); while (i<5) x[i++] = ' '; x[5] = 0;`

Comment: If you want a C solution, how come you used the C++ tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
printf("%-5.5s", x);
```

The format conversion `%-5.5s` is made up of the following:

- <kbd>-</kbd>  (flag) Pad the output on the right, if necessary
- <kbd>5</kbd>  (field width) Output at least 5 characters
- <kbd>.5</kbd> (precision) Use at most 5 characters of the string
- <kbd>s</kbd>  (conversion) The corresponding argument is a `char*` pointing to a string.

For more information, see `man sprintf`

If your intention was to truncate or extend the *result* of a call to `sprintf` (which is a possible interpretation of a comment), then the answer is to use `snprintf`, but only if you are prepared for the truncation to be at the end of the formatted output. Here's a little toy:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int limit = atoi(argv[1]);
  for (int j = 2; j < argc - 1; j+=2) {
    int n = atoi(argv[j]);
    char buffer[limit + 1];
    # format split into two for explanatory purposes:
    #   %d %s   is the format for the output
    #   %*.0s   takes two arguments, length and "",
    #           and adds length spaces to the end of the output
    # Because we're using snprintf, the output is truncated.
    if (snprintf(buffer, limit+1, "%d %s" "%*.0s",
                 n, argv[j+1],
                 limit, "") < 0) {
      perror("snprintf");
      return 1;
    }
    if (strlen(buffer) != limit)
      fprintf(stderr, "buffer length is %zd instead of %d\n",
                      strlen(buffer), limit);
    printf("|%s|\n", buffer);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Test run:

```
$ ./snp 12 3 kangaroos 10 kangaroos 125 kangaroos \
           3 koalas 14 koalas 173 koalas 1294 koalas \
           12964 koalas 127347 koalas
|3 kangaroos |
|10 kangaroos|
|125 kangaroo|
|3 koalas    |
|14 koalas   |
|173 koalas  |
|1294 koalas |
|12964 koalas|
|127347 koala|
```

Comment: This is good, but its problematic for my setting where i want to use sprintf with additional %d's in the string itself

Comment: @user124627: Why does that affect anything? The width and precision codes only apply to the single `s` format code (just like `%5.2f', where the 5 and 2 only apply to that `f` code.)

Comment: i guess i will try this out, it looks look it will cut it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the third `printf` call, if you want to display character at position 1, you should do:

`printf("%c", x[1]);`

To append character strings, have a look at `strcat`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/?kw=strcat

Ex:

```
char first[1000] = "Hello", sec[] = " world";
strcat(first, sec); /* destination, source */
```

But `strcat` is unsafe, so make your own safe strcat:

```
char *safecat(char *dest, const char *src, size_t siz)
{
    return strncat(dest, src, siz);
}
```

And to read at most *n* characters, read about `fgets`, passing `stdin` as the stream: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/?kw=fgets

Ex:

```
char buf[MAXBUF];
fgets(buf, MAXBUF, stdin); /* this only reads MAXBUF - 1  characters. The
                              rest is left in stdin */
```

Comment: for some reason, i still overflow when i use fgets;    char g[] = "  fgfghhh %d      %d gghg   %02d:%d      "; char b[40]; strcat(b, g); fgets(b, 40, stdin);

Comment: Try to make the capacity of `b` bigger to, say, 1000

Answer (score 1):

well you can write your own function for it:

```
void print_five(char *s)
{
    int i = 0;
    char d[6] = {0};
    strncpy(d, s, 5);
    if(strlen(d) < 5) {
        for(i = strlen(d); i < 5; i++) {
            d[i] = ' ';
        }
    }
    printf("%s", d);    

}


int main(void)
{
    char d[10] = "helloooo";
    char m[4] = "h";
    print_five(d);
    printf("continued\n"); //hellocontinued
    print_five(m);
    printf("continued\n"); //h    continued
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: This is good, but I am still overflowing. I still get characters/junk above max length when I print out.

Comment: also you might consider voting up if the code helps you:=)